# Problema ao utilizar o laço while

Tags: javascript

Tenho um `input` em uma página onde digito o CEP e posso calcular qual o valor e tempo estimado para entrega de um produto para cada região.

Ao clicar no botão de calcular ele vai mostrar um box carregado via Ajax com as respectivas informações, o problema é que a plataforma tem um pequeno problema (bug) e mostra 8 dias úteis até mesmo para produtos que deveriam ser 4 dias úteis.

 Meu objetivo é fazer uma checagem para se o produto tiver um preço maior que R$149,90 ele executa uma função para mudar o texto de 8 dias úteis para 4 dias úteis.

 O problema é que esse elemento não é carregado logo após clicar no botão, ele só aparece quando a requisição Ajax é completada (e eu não tenho acesso aos scripts que fazem essa requisição). 

 Então eu enfrento problemas como a velocidade de conexão do usuário (que é variável de um para outro), e os elementos não existem logo após eu clicar no botão.

 Eu tentei usar o laço while, mas estou com problemas, vejam o código:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

if( document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').textContent === 'OK' ){

    document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(){

        var preco = /(\d+)(\,)(\d+)/.exec( document.getElementsByClassName('preco-promocional')[1].textContent );

        if( preco[1] > 149 ){
            while( typeof( document.getElementsByClassName('prazo')[1] ) === 'undefined' ){
                while( document.getElementsByClassName('prazo')[1].textContent === '8 dias úteis' ){
                    document.getElementsByClassName('prazo')[1].textContent = '4 dias úteis';
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

});
```

A lógica seria checar enquanto esse elemento for `undefined`, e então, quando ele deixar de ser, eu executo outro laço verificar se o texto é `8 dias úteis` e enquanto for, ele tenta mudar para `4 dias úteis`.

Grato pela atenção

Comment: dá para ser mais específico em relação ao problema? não está funcionando, está trancando a página, se é retornada alguma mensagem de erro, etc.

Comment: Eu tentaria com promises, utilizando jquery.
http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso vai crashar muitos browsers... ter um while a correr desse modo vai parar o browser. Em casos em que algo é **mesmo** necessário a solução é um setInterval.

O que você pode fazer é esconder o elemento pai desse elemento final, e voltar a mostrar só quando tiver mudado o valor.

E já agora teste `typeof preco[1]` para ver se dá numero. Se não o seu `if` não vai funcionar certo.

Sugestão de código:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var botaoSubmit = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
    if (botaoSubmit.textContent === 'OK') {
        botaoSubmit.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var preco = /(\d+)(\,)(\d+)/.exec(document.getElementsByClassName('preco-promocional')[1].textContent);
            if (preco[1] > 149) {
                var prazo = document.getElementsByClassName('prazo')[1];
                var espera = setInterval(function(){
                    if (!prazo) return;
                    prazo.textContent = '4 dias úteis';
                    clearInterval(espera);
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
});
```